# How to preserve value of TextInput in React-Native paper?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-paper

I have two screens, A and B. Screen A contains just a react-native-paper TextInput, e.g.,

```
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    error={error}
                    label='Enter something'
                    mode='outlined'
                    onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                    value ={this.state.text}
                />
            </View>
```

In above case, when I move from screen A to screen B, and if I press back to come to screen A, the value of TextInput goes, though `this.state.text` has whatever the data I filled on screen A.

If I hardcode the value, then it remains preserved after navigating from A to B and then back to A. E.g.,

```
    <View>
        <TextInput
            error={error}
            label='Enter something'
            mode='outlined'
            onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
            value ={'Hello World'}
        />
    </View>
```

Please tell me how can I make sure that the value of TextInput remains preserved when I move from screen B to screen A. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you navigating trough the screens?

Comment: @Auticcat Through props.navigation of react-navigation

Comment: You can pass the text value as a prop when navigating or save the last text value in asyncstorage and fetch it when the screen A loads

Comment: @Helen lux In react-navigation, constructor or any of the lifecycle method doesn't get called, when moving from screen B to A, as A was never unmounted. So how will I fetch that value?

Comment: Which navigator are you using? A StackNavigator? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you said, screen A is not unmounting and, even tho the value in `this.state.text` remains untouched, graphically the value has been emptied. In my case, it's working as expected.

ScreenA

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

export default class ScreenA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: "" };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                error={false}
                label="Enter something"
                mode="outlined"
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                onBlur={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenB")}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

ScreenB

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class LoadingScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> ScreenB </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Navigator

```
const RoutesConfig = {
    ScreenA: {
        screen: ScreenA,
    },
    ScreenB: {
        screen: ScreenB,
    }
};

const StackNavigatorConfigs = {
    initialRouteName: "ScreenA",
};

export default createStackNavigator(RoutesConfig, StackNavigatorConfigs);
```

While in `ScreenA` i write whatever i need and then navigate to ScreenB when the `TextInput` triggers `onBlur`. Using the StackNavigator's `Header` i navigate back and the value is still saved and displayed in the `TextInput`.

If the value is still saved in the `state` (if I've understood correctly it is) you can use the `withNavigationFocus` HOC provided by `react.navigation`. Using this you can see if the value is actually stored and see if triggering a re-render will show the value graphically.

For example, using my `ScreenA` sample:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-paper";
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";

class ScreenA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: "" };
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => { 
        if ( prevProps.isFocused === false && this.props.isFocused === true ){
            this.setState({ text : this.state.text })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                error={false}
                label="Enter something"
                mode="outlined"
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                onBlur={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenB")}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(ScreenA);
```

Answer (score -1):

I normally use redux to store values which helps this situration. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

```js
//reducers/inputReducer.js
import {
   UPDATE_INPUT
} from '../actions'

const initialState = {
   input = null
}

function input(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_INPUT: {
           return {
               ...state,
               input = action.value
           }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default input
```

```js
//input.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { updateInput } from './actions.js'
...
<TextInput
            error={error}
            label='Enter something'
            mode='outlined'
            onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
            onChangeText={text => this.props.updateInput(text)}
            value ={this.props.input}
        />
...
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        input: state.input
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {
           updateInput
        },
        dispatch
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(input);
```

```js
//actions.js

export const UPDATE_INPUT = "UPDATE_INPUT";
export function updateInput(value) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_INPUT,
        value: value
    }
}
```

Note, you still need to setup store and reducer,

Edit: Other part of setup redux (hopefully I didnt miss anything)

```
//store.js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import combineReducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(combineReducers);

export default store;
```

```js
//reducers/index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import input from './inputReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  input
});
```

```js
//index.js

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```